# how to generate a migration file with prisma

Tags: prisma

I tried this in the repository's prisma folder

`npx prisma migrate dev --name add_finance_tables`

but it shows this in the terminal

**
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": CockroachDB database "defaultdb"**

i'm expecting a new timestamped migration folder to be made in the migrations folder named timestamp_add_finance_tables (or something like that name)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago but the fix is to first make a change in your `schema.prisma` file. Add whatever changes you need. Then run the command you are running. It will then notice the changes you made on the file and generate the SQL needed to achieve that change. Hope this helps.